# click a button to load a different video player into div

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, video

i'm working on adding a video to the home page of a site i'm working on.  ideally, i'd like to show the youtube version by default, and add a button underneath that says something like "don't have access to youtube?  click here to watch an alternate version".

once clicked, a different player will load into the same video div and replace the youtube version.

we have the video uploaded to youtube, and also have an html5 version on the site that is played via the video.js plugin for wordpress.

how can i load the alternate html5 video player into the div via a button click (without refreshing the page if possible)?  i'm assuming this can be done via javascript / jquery / ajax somehow, but I'm not sure how to do this (my js level is *novice*).

thanks!!

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: If you're unsure how `click` events work in jQuery, then I'd politely correct you by saying your js level is novice, *not* intermediate. :-) Take a look at the jQuery documentation for `.click()`, `.html()`, and `.attr()`. I am sure they will be very helpful!

Comment: haha, thanks guys - yes, novice it is:)  i have a basic understanding of `click` events and assumed that would be the way to go, but when it comes to putting everything together is where i tend to get stuck. thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clear the div out with:

```
$("#yourDivID").empty()
```

Then populate the div with new content

```
var newHtml = "Whatever you want!"
$("#yourDivID").append(newHtml);
```

Or

```
$("#yourDivID").html(newHtml);
```

Here's a very primitive example of replacing content in a Div: http://jsfiddle.net/FJuwd/

Comment: Or: `$("#yourDivID").html(newHtml);`

Answer (score 0):

Html

```
<div id="myvideodiv"> </div>
```

In script

```
mybutton.click(function(){

    playerMethod("myvideodiv").setup({ //here player intializations based on sepecific type
        file: "/uploads/example.mp4",
        height: 360,
        image: "/uploads/example.jpg",
        width: 640
    });


})
```

see [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13517783/load-video-into-jw-player-using-jquery) here.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery solution: Just create div and populate with video on button click. Many ways to do this. The check for length is only there to eliminate putting another video up.

```
<div id="player"><div>
<button id="clickme">Click to play video</button>   

 $("#clickme").on("click", function(e) {
    if($('#myfileplayer').length == 0) {
        var mydiv = $("#player");
        var myvideo = $("<video id='myfileplayer' src='http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.ogv' width='320' height='240' controls></video>");
        mydiv.append(myvideo);
    }
});
```

See [example](http://jsfiddle.net/VnvvL/1/)

Answer (score 0):

thanks so much everyone for all of the help.  love this place.

i was actually able to work this out more easily by just toggling divs that contain the two different videos.  not sure why i didn't think of this initially.  doesn't actually *remove* the content, just hides it, but i think it will work for me.

html

```
<div id="youtube">my youtube vid</div>
<div id="html5" style="display:none;">my alternate vid</div>

<input type="button" value="switch video" id="click"/>
```

jquery

```
$(function(){
  $('#click').click(function(){
     $('#youtube').toggle();
     $('#html5').toggle(); 
  });
});
```

i also tried this with the js, so the youtube video would be removed & stop playing when the divs are toggled

```
$(function(){
  $('#click').click(function(){
     $('#youtube').toggle();
     $('#html5').toggle(); 
     $('#youtube').empty();

  });
});
```

this works, but i wasn't sure how to add the youtube video back when toggling back. not really a big deal - just something i was curious about.  i'm assuming it can be done with .append.

problem with this is that both of the vids exist in the wordpress page as shortcodes, so it complicates things a bit.  i just wrapped the shortdoces in divs with these ids in the wordpress page to get the toggle working, and added the js to my page template.  thx again!